# 3D representation of a transcendental equation

Tags: plotting

Given a transcendental equation $F * exp [x] + x * y + sqrt[F-y] = 0$, is there a way for *Mathematica* to automatically 3D-plot `F[x,y]`  depending on `x` and `y` ?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a transcendental equation, for the very reason that you can actually just solve for `F` in terms of elementary functions, as shown by @Kuba.

Comment: @Kuba. Oh right! Got the names switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be just

```
ContourPlot3D[F Exp[x] + x y + Sqrt[F - y] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {F, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately there are some problems because the `Sqrt` term is complex sometimes. A better plot is obtained by squaring the equation and using `RegionFunction` to eliminate the extra solutions:

```
ContourPlot3D[(F Exp[x] + x y)^2 == F - y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {F, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, F}, F Exp[x] + x y < 0]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not a great deal. First you solve it:

```
    sl = Solve[F*Exp[x] + x*y + Sqrt[F - y] == 0, F]

(*  {{F -> 1/2 E^(-2 x) (1 - 2 E^x x y - Sqrt[
      1 - 4 E^(2 x) y - 4 E^x x y])}, {F -> 
   1/2 E^(-2 x) (1 - 2 E^x x y + Sqrt[1 - 4 E^(2 x) y - 4 E^x x y])}}  *)
```

and then plot:

```
 Plot3D[{sl[[1, 1, 2]], sl[[2, 1, 2]]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}]
```

and should see this:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Try evaluating `F*Exp[x] + x*y + Sqrt[F - y] /. sl /. {x -> -1, y -> -1}`: neither "solution" satisfies the original equation.